# How to rewrite errors returned by an underlying server at HAProxy?

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy

I have a JBoss cluster under Apache HTTP servers, which is in turn under the HAProxy load-balancer. Whenever a JBoss application server goes down, Apache shows the 503 error screen. Is there a way I can bubble up the 503 response to HAProxy from Apache and handle it at HAProxy ?

Comment: More information about your Apache installation might assist. There are several solutions for this. Since you are running a jboss cluster, have you looked as leveraging Apache's mod_balancer, along with using AJP in Jboss? This is how we handle our load-balancing, and it makes it fault tolerant.

Comment: Do you want to show custom error page on 503 with HaProxy, or? What do you want do to with HaProxy?

Comment: @EirikToft, I user Apache's mod_proxy. My concern is not the JBoss server going down. Instead of showing Apache's default 503 page, I would like to show the custom 503 error page on HAProxy.

Since, HAProxy is my point of reverse proxy I'm guessing it is possible.

Comment: @JakovSosic, I have a custom error page on 503 setup on HAProxy, it is not being used as the Apache's default 503 page is being served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the ErrorDocument directive. There is documentation of it at [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)

Let's say in your document root you have a sub directory called "errors", you could put in either httpd.conf or the .htaccess file in your document root:

```
ErrorDocument 503 /errors/error_503.html
```

Then write the error_503.html to look however you wish. You can also use text, or even use a URL that directs to a completely different server/document. Some use this latter method so that they can handle an error message by passing control to another set of scripts altogether.

Comment: I found out that bubbling up the error to HAProxy was simply complicating things. I ended up using the configuration you suggested. Thanks.